# Short Import Typescript path mapping doesnt work in Angular 8 Project

Tags: json, angular, typescript, path, tsconfig

My Angular Project Structure looks like this:

[image]

My goal is to be able to import the register.component.ts into the auth-routing.module.ts with

```
import { RegisterComponent } from '@pages/auth/authpages/register/register.component';
```

For that, i added the path to my tsconfig.json, which looks like this:

```
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "typeRoots": ["node_modules/@types"],
    "importHelpers": true,
    "target": "es2015",
    "lib": [
      "es2018",
      "dom"
    ],
    "baseUrl": "src",
    "paths": {

      "@pages/*": ["app/pages*"]
    }
  },
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "fullTemplateTypeCheck": true,
    "strictInjectionParameters": true
  }
}
```

For some reason, it still does not work. 
The component is properly exported and can be targeted with standard ts paths.
Does anyone have a clue whats the problem?

Comment: What error do you get? Could you check if `"baseUrl": "./src",` and `"@pages/*": ["./app/pages/*"]` make any difference? Maybe even just `"@pages/*": ["app/pages/*"]` will do the job

Comment: It just says "cant find module from path", the suggested code does not change anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try change this

```
"@pages/*": ["app/pages*"]
```

to

```
"@pages/*": ["app/pages/*"]
```

Comment: The solution worked partly, now the error is gone in vs code, but when running the app, it prints the same error in the console. Dont get why

Comment: ERROR in src/app/pages/auth/auth-routing.module.ts:4:35 - error TS2307: Cannot find module '@pages/auth/authpages/register/register.component'.

Comment: hmmm.... weird i try your setting it working on my local. rerun the app also same ?

Comment: its still the same, maybe its because the route /auth/register is set up as lazy loaded. But its wierd that vs code says no error and node says error

Comment: i found a way to fix this, i changed the baseURL to "../src" in tsconfig.spec and tsconfig.app too. before it was just "./" Now vs code is not happy with that and marks the three files as "problem" but the app compiles with no error. Maybe you have a fix for that? If not i will still accept your solution

Comment: oh, because your baseURL at tsconfig is src, that why u need to change it on tsconfig.spec and tsconfig.app too. by default when u create ng application the baseUrl is point to ./ actually why u want to change that haha